# Interpretation of double log model when variables are ratios

Tags: econometrics, interpretation, logarithm, ratio

I am running a double log model. My dependent variable is GDP growth per capita.   My independent variables are military expenditure as share of GDP and gross capital formation as share of GDP.  All three variables are in log form.  My question is, how can I interpret my results when my variables are in log and ratio form?

Comment: Please elaborate what do we understand  understand by double log model?  And let us know what is nature of your problem ?

Comment: sir how can i interpret my coefficient results when my independent variables are in log and ratio form  actually i am running a double log model
 where my dependent variable is log of GDP per capita my independent variables are log of military expenditure as share of GDP and gross capital formation as share of GDP

Comment: simple double log interpretation we do as if 1 percent change accure in aur independent variable aur dependent varible will increase or decrease by that percent other thing renaming the same but in my case my independent  variables are in log and ratio form. how can i interpret my results?

Comment: Your wording in the body - double log  model tends to convey something  -  log-transformatiion of the data .you have not mentioned the technique for analysis and results. Why do you want to use log ?

Comment: i follow the Solow growth model and applied the GMM technique

Comment: i am only interested how to interpret the results of those variables which are in ratio form in double log model

Comment: there is a large variation in my data to reduced the variation i applied log and by applying log my results are also better than before thats the reason i applied log but now the problem of interpretation how can i interpret my independent variables which are in log and ratio form for example if coefficient value of log of military expenditure as share of gdp is 0.025 and the coefficient value of log of gross capital formation as share of GDP 0.030 then how can i interpret this when dependent variable is log of growth gdp per capita .? – Agha tayyab ilyas 11 hours ago

Comment: What is your interpretation ?

Comment: my interpretation is if one percent increase in military expenditure as share of GDP then growth of GDP per capita decreases by 0.025 percent other thing remaining the same. but i am confused is this interpretation true?

Comment: You must define growth of  GDP per capita ? Also you seem to be induldging in log of ratio or percentage -based independent variables.It may be useful, if the analysis or a parrt of it is prsented , it could help you with a faster and correct response.